# NSCalendar dateFromComponents returns wrong date

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I'm writing a Category on NSDate to create an NSDate from an ISO 8601 string representation (YYYYMMDD).

Even though I pass 20010226, I get back 2001-02-25 23:00:00 +0000. what am I doing wrong?

This is the code:

```
-(id) initWithISO8601Date: (NSString *) iso8601Date{
    // Takes a date in the YYYYMMDD form


    int year = [[iso8601Date substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4)] integerValue];
    int month = [[iso8601Date substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(4, 2)] integerValue];
    int day = [[iso8601Date substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6,2)] integerValue];

    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [comps setYear:year];
    [comps setMonth:month];
    [comps setDay:day];


    self = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];
    NSLog(@"%@", self);

    [comps release];

    return self;

}
```

Comment: You may be interested in my ISO 8601 parser and unparser: https://bitbucket.org/boredzo/iso-8601-parser-unparser It handles all valid ISO 8601 formats, including with separators.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was the Time Zone (I'm on GMT -1).  The correct code is:

```
-(id) initWithISO8601Date: (NSString *) iso8601Date{
    // Takes a date in the YYYYMMDD form
    int year = [[iso8601Date substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4)] integerValue];
    int month = [[iso8601Date substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(4, 2)] integerValue];
    int day = [[iso8601Date substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6,2)] integerValue];

    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [comps setYear:year];
    [comps setMonth:month];
    [comps setDay:day];

    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    [cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
    self = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];


    [comps release];

    return self;

}
```

Comment: It is weird that NSCalendar operates w/ local timeZone by default instead of being in GMT, isn't it?

Comment: Totally! Forgot this again just today.